# Probably an average algebra question, but I need help with the interpretation.

Tags: contest-math

For the function *f*, *f*(2(*x*)) = *x*^2+*x*−2 for all real numbers *x*. Let *a* and *b* be the sum and product, respectively, of the roots of the equation f((*x*)/2) = 4. Find *a + b*.

Comment: which part of the question do you need help interpretating?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How is f((x)/2) related to f(2x)? I apologize for my inability to use MathJax. I will use it in my succeeding posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $$f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = f\left(2\cdot\frac{x}{4}\right)$$

and then use the formula for $f(2x)$ on the right expression.